# Filtering specific elements from UI using selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium

I've a  page where there are sections of class elements. each top class elements contains sub classes inturn which has details related to that class. I need to get that class elements for which have used below code. I got the details into collection but when running the script, the filtering out of specific elements is not working. Could any one check on this. below is the code I've written.

```
List al= driver.findElements(By.css("class name"));
if(al.get(i).getText().equals(specific class))
{
 List detailslist=al.get(i).findElements(" sub details of that group");
 if(detailslist.get(i).getText().equals("abc"){
  add that elements.      
  }
}
```

Comment: to get child elements(sub groups) of a parent(group) use `parentElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"))`

Comment: please share the html code or example?